Object appears to be denser when closer to the X-ray source
When imaging a sheet of Polymethyl methacrylate (PMMA)  with 40 kV, it appears to absorb more X-rays the closer it is to the source. Conversely, it appears less dense when closer to the detector.
Scattering might explain it (more scattered energy hits the detector when it's closer), but there's no obvious relationship to the distance to the detector - at least as far as I can tell from a limited number of quickly made images.
What is happening and what simple test could I run to confirm it?

"It appears to..." - what are you measuring this with? Appearances can be, well, deceiving.

Tungsten anode and flat panel detector, not sure what scintillator. Aside from minor beam intensity fluctuations, the setup is constant. Only the object position is varied.

Does the camera auto-adjust the exposure?

No. I'm pretty sure it's a physics thing (or geometry)

Do a thought experiment.  Think about your imaging geometry.  Remember that scatter is mostly isotropic.  Start with the PMMA close to the tube.  Think about the proportion of scatter and primary x-rays detected.  Where are the primary beam x-rays and scattered x-rays going to go when your PMMA is close to the tube?  Move the PMMA closer to the detector and think about what's being detected.  Keep doing that until the PMMA is at the detector.

@imabug So you are confirming my suspicion? Are there other effects in play?
